# Nesting React components which fetch state asynchronously causes Flux dispatch chain

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, flux

When I have multiple async requests out for data, how can I guarantee the responses won't happen in the same event loop? Those responses will both trigger dispatches from the action creators causing dispatch within a dispatch message.

Note that the data are **not** dependent on each other so using `waitFor()` doesn't do anything.

For example, two components:

```
let Post = React.createClass({
    getInitialState () {
        return {
            post: PostStore.getPost(postID) //This triggers an API call
        }
    },

    render () {
        return (
            <Authors/>
        );
    }
});

let Authors = React.createClass({
    getInitialState () {
        return {
            authors: UserStore.getAuthors() //This also triggers an API call
        }
    }
});
```

I get `dispatch within a dispatch` invariant every time. Now if I were to bootstrap the data or put `UserStore.getAuthors()` dispatch behind the `setTimeout(func, 0)` hack it will work fine since it forces the second API call to dispatch on the next event loop. However, I'm sure that at some point I'm going to run into this issue again. For instance, what if I have a twitter feed that updates via API requests on a poll? How can I guarantee that the API request won't come back and interfere with another dispatch?

I can bootstrap data like so:

```
PostStore.initialize(window.posts);
UserStore.initialize(window.users);
```

Why doesn't that create a dispatch within a dispatch invariant? Is it not two dispatches at the same time?

---

**Update 11/16/15**

I have switch to [Redux](http://redux.js.org/), which is the better Flux implementation and solves a lot of these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this implementation so all the dispatch are queued and I never have any problem:

```
var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;
var assign = require('object-assign');
var Constants = require('Constants');
var async = require('async');

var PayloadSources = Constants.PayloadSources;

var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

var queue = async.queue( function (task, callback) {
    var payload = {
        source:PayloadSources[task.source],
        action: task.action
    };
    AppDispatcher.dispatch(payload);
    callback();

}, 1);

var AppDispatcher = assign(dispatcher, {
    handleServerAction: function (action) {
        queue.push({source : 'SERVER_ACTION', action : action});
        // console.log(queue);
    },
    handleViewAction: function (action) {
        queue.push({source: 'VIEW_ACTION', action : action});
        // console.log(queue);
    }
});


module.exports = AppDispatcher;
```

Comment: Seems like a good approach without messing with the Flux pattern too much. I know there is a lot of debate about the dispatcher being completely synchronous. Your solution may work to prevent the rare case of API responses intercepting the dispatcher until a more "official" answer is released.

Comment: Indeed, also this solution is not mine but I can't find the original source, it's from a discussion about this topic on github. Glad it helped

Comment: finally you used the answer I provided or something else ?

Comment: I'm gonna give the answer to you since your solution works, but after searching online for a while I have come across [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) which seems very promising. I'm going to play around with that and see if it's a better fit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with redux, it's a new way to manage models(stores) and dependencies ? Where no dispatcher is needed ?

Comment: Your application has a single state and instead of stores you use "reducers" `(state, action) => newState` to update state. Then you just send state down from the top every time it changes. It removes the need for events and the dispatcher and allows you to snapshot, serialize, and deserialize your state between server and client very easily.

I would definitely read through the [documenation](http://rackt.github.io/redux/) or just watch this awesome [presentation] (https://youtu.be/xsSnOQynTHs) by Dan Abromov (Flux starts at the ten minute mark).